# Retrieve selected date from iOS native calendar app

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I am able to access iOS native calendar by using following code

```
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

Now i want to get the date which user has selected. How to retrieve selected date from native iOS app.
I don't want to use date picker.

Comment: Not clear , do you want to open iCal with selected date ?

Comment: I want to open the app and then select the date

Comment: I am confused. Here is what i gathered from what you've said. You want the user to open up your app and select a date. And then you want to retrieve the selected date that the user selected. And you do not want to use a picker view to do it. So tell me this, if you do not want to use a pickerView, then what do you want to use?

Comment: @Coder seems it is not possible to get the selected date. Only events and reminders can be fetched via notifications.